# Preposition of manner placement

Tags: questions

> 1.Three people are died in road accident at Haima.
>
> 2.Three people are died at Haima in road accident.

Here I am not sure either sentence is fine and can be spoken in English either way.

Comment: Three people **died**, not *are died*, in **a** road accident. The order of the two preposition phrases doesn't matter since they refer to the same "scene" and neither is inherently more important than the other.

Comment: If the report is 'hot news', you could also say "Three people have died following a road accident in Haima"

Comment: I want to know which position of at haima  correct? Or both position correct?

Comment: Either position is correct. To simplify @StoneyB 's explanation, where the people died (at Haima) and how the people died (in *a* road accident) are both equally important, so it doesn't matter which comes first.

Comment: It's important to understand that what is wrong with both sentences is not the position of the adverbial preposition phrase _at Haima_, but the lack of a deteminer before the noun _accident_, the failure to capitalize the proper noun _Haima_, and the passive use of the verb _die_. Intransitive verbs in English cannot be used to form a passive. This means that _neither_ sentence should be spoken.

Answer (score 1):

The 1st sentence is closest.

> Three people died in a road accident at Haima.

Alternatively, but much less common:

> Three people are dead due to a road accident at Haima.